# How do I host a Domain Name for my Website?

Tags: server, dns, web, debian, host

I want to host a domain name for my website, like www.mywebsite.com. I want to host a domain name, because then I will not have to pay for a premium service , like NameCheap. When users go to www.mywebsite.com, it will be my website. How can I host a domain name? I have a server running Debian 8 Jessie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working this way.
First you need a registered domain "example.com" in some sort of hosting provider like [OVh.com](http://ovh.com), then you can use [apache2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps) to host your website

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, I understand what you mean. Though, I am now going to get a paid domain from NameCheap! Thanks for the answer though!